# What is a good web app for tracking anything (not specific to one category)?

Tags: webapp-rec

Last year, [Wired Magazine](http://www.wired.com) published a seried of articles called ["Living by the Numbers"](http://www.wired.com/medtech/health/magazine/17-07/lbnp_nutrition), which explored the advantages of tracking personal data to help reach goals in the areas of [excercise](http://www.wired.com/medtech/health/magazine/17-07/lbnp_exercise), [health](http://www.wired.com/medtech/health/magazine/17-07/lbnp_health), and [nutrition](http://www.wired.com/medtech/health/magazine/17-07/lbnp_nutrition).  This got me thinking that tracking data for *anything* can be useful for reaching goals: keeping up with books you've read, logging food consumption, tracking the minutes spent in your daily commute, etc.

Some sites do a great job on focusing on a very narrow category (such as finance or nutrition), but I'm interested in a site that lets me track and visualize data in *any* category for the purpose of helping me achieve personal goals.

I've been using a web app called [daytum](http://daytum.com) for the past few days and have been pleased with its simplicity, but it could be better.  Before I invest too much time (and potentially money) into that web app, I'm interested to find out **other good web apps for tracking anything that is not too closely tied to a specific category.**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just use a Google Spreadsheet to do that?

Or if you need something more database beyond a simple spreadsheet, you can try [Ragic Builder](http://www.ragic.com). It has pretty good search and analytical database features.

Answer (score 1):

Ben, here are a few options:

- http://lifehacker.com/346671/track-goal-progress-and-to+dos-on-google-calendar
- http://42goals.com
- http://lifehacker.com/5439026/five-best-goal+tracking-tools

Comment: those look like great links for keeping track of data specific to goals. On the flip-side, I wonder what other sites are out there for tracking data, regardless of whether they are tied to goals.

Comment: If you're still looking for things related to tracking goals, I'm also launching http://goals.com soon. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

[DAYTUM](http://daytum.com) is a pretty nicely designed web app that helps you track things (numerical things) that may or may not be tied to goals.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [trackthisforme.com](http://www.trackthisfor.me/). They have a web and Android app as of this writing.

Via [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/tldr/2014/11/17/7233479/a-workout-app-made-me-a-better-gamer).